# Подсчет времени проведенного на определенной странице

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица куда каждые 2 минуты пишет информацию о том кто из пользователей, сколько их всего, находятся на данной странице. Каждая запись фиксируется временем проверки в виде `timestamp`.

Вопрос: Как подсчитать сколько максимум было на каждой странице, и сколько (приблизительно) времени на каждой из них провел определенный пользователь (в примере с `ID` `4`) за последние сутки?

- Описание таблицы:

`stats_id` - *AUTO_INCREMENT*

`stats_user_id` - *ID* юзера

`stats_time` - Время проверки

`stats_user_cnt` - Сколько всего человек на старнице во время проверки

`stats_url` - страница

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `stats_id` mediumint(21) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stats_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_user_cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stats_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=110 ;



INSERT INTO `stats` (`stats_id`, `stats_user_id`, `stats_time`, `stats_user_cnt`, `stats_url`) VALUES
(5, 4, 1449943803, 26, 'index'),
(10, 4, 1449943923, 26, 'index'),
(12, 4, 1449944043, 21, 'news'),
(20, 4, 1449944163, 23, 'news'),
(22, 4, 1449944282, 22, 'news'),
(27, 4, 1449944403, 20, 'news'),
(32, 4, 1449944523, 23, 'news'),
(37, 4, 1449944642, 19, 'news'),
(42, 4, 1449944763, 19, 'news'),
(47, 4, 1449944882, 22, 'news'),
(51, 4, 1449945003, 20, 'news'),
(56, 4, 1449945123, 17, 'index'),
(61, 4, 1449945243, 16, 'index'),
(66, 4, 1449945363, 17, 'index'),
(71, 4, 1449945482, 23, 'index'),
(79, 4, 1449945602, 22, 'index'),
(81, 4, 1449945723, 21, 'index'),
(86, 4, 1449945843, 23, 'index'),
(91, 4, 1449945963, 24, 'index'),
(96, 4, 1449946083, 26, 'index'),
(101, 4, 1449946202, 21, 'index'),
(106, 4, 1449946323, 24, 'index');



 Первая проверка первой страницы: юзер1. - (1, 1, 1449943803, 12, 'index_1')
 Вторая проверка первой страницы: юзер1, юзер2.  - (2, 1, 1449943804, 26, 'index_1'), (3, 2, 1449943805, 6, 'index_1')
 Третья проверка первой страницы: юзер2.  - (4, 2, 1449943806, 23, 'index_1')
 Первая проверка второй страницы: юзер2.  - (5, 2, 1449943807, 22, 'index_2')
 Вторая проверка второй страницы: никого нет. - (Нет юзера нет статы, такого не будет)
 Третья проверка второй страницы: юзер2.   - (6, 2, 1449943807, 3, 'index_2')
 Первая и третья проверки третьей страницы: никого нет.  - (Нет юзера нет статы, такого не будет)
 Вторая проверка третьей страницы: юзер2.   - (7, 2, 1449943807, 2, 'index_3')
 Юзер3 нигде не засветился. - (нет записи, он всегда светится)
```

Comment: "за последние сутки" - `...WHERE stats_time >= UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` (покажет, например, с обеда прошлого дня до обеда текущего), либо `...WHERE stats_time >= DATE(UTC_TIMESTAMP())` - покажет за текущие астрономические сутки (т.е. с 12 ночи до, например, обеда). По данным не совсем понял - т.е. если на странице в момент проверки будет 26 человек, то будет 26 записей, которые отличаются только stats_id и stats_user_id? А если в момент проверки вообще не было пользователей - что тогда будет в базе?

Comment: если будет 26 на странице то новых записей не появится, stats_user_id будет как бы всегда находится там. Понимаю что глупо звучит, но описывать все займет много времени. Мне нужно самое главное понять как подсчитать среднее время каждой страницы.

Comment: чтобы вам понять, а нам объяснить - нам надо знать что у вас там находится. Приведите пример данных в следующей ситуации: есть три пользователя, три страницы, три проверки каждой страницы. Первая проверка первой страницы: юзер1. Вторая проверка первой страницы: юзер1, юзер2. Третья проверка первой страницы: юзер2. Первая проверка второй страницы: юзер2. Вторая проверка второй страницы: никого нет. Третья проверка второй страницы: юзер2. Первая и третья проверки третьей страницы: никого нет. Вторая проверка третьей страницы: юзер2. Юзер3 нигде не засветился. Какие данные у вас будут в базе?

Comment: Там и так запутано все, вы меня еще больше путаете :( Показал пример что он дас не знаю. Выборка всегда будет проходить по конкретному stats_user_id думаю мне нужно было не приводить его в пример что б не путать вас. Вопрос о том как же подсчитать время проведенное на странице остается :(

Comment: у вас подход корявый. Я зашел на страницу сегодня в 12:00, потом зашел на эту страницу через неделю в 12:00, больше никто на страницу не заходил. И как теперь мне определить - я был на странице всего пару минут, либо сидел там все это время, просто проверка редко проходила? Только если считать, что проверка проходит не реже какого-то периода. Например, если после логина в течение 5 минут не было проверки - значит и на странице не сидел. В вашем случае проще будет еще одну таблицу сессий сделать - по крону заполняете ее и проведенное время определяете по ней, а не по текущей

Comment: Тогда заполнять таблицу сессий можно было бы из php - выбираете все проверки начиная с определенной, сортируете их по пользователям и в php высчитываете продолжительность сессии каждого пользователя. Где-то был похожий вопрос, там как раз рассматривается какой подход надо использовать.

Comment: Говорю же что там все очень сильно и без того запутано. Проверка идет по крону каждую 2 минуты и если вы зашли в 12:00 и вышли и потом через неделю опять зашли и вышли то вы общее время провели не более 4 минуты на странице. С учетом что мне нужно приблизительно этого достаточно. P.S. Вы меня натолкнули на мысль что нужно посчитать количество записей по странице и умножить на 2 секунды. На данный момент другого варианта я не вижу :( Изменение структуры БД не предусмотрено